# Why my node isn't getting deleted on using free() or delete

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

I am trying to implement a binary search tree in c++ in which I implemented a
`deletenode()`
method using double pointers, but my nodes aren't getting deleted on using the predefined methods such as `free()` and `delete`. Kindly help me out ?

I have been searching for videos or articles on youtube as well as geeks for geeks but they all have implemented using a single pointer so I am unable to find a reference in this case particularly nor near to it. I am trying to solve this from last week unable to implement successfully, some nodes are getting deleted some are not I am unable to find the reason behind this, please also provide me why my code isn't working as expected

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node {
    struct node *left = NULL;
    int key;
    struct node *right = NULL;
} node;

void addNode(node **r, int k)
{
    if (*r == NULL)
    {
        node *q = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        q->key = k;
        *r = q;
        (*r)->left = NULL;
        (*r)->right = NULL;
        return;
    }
    node *q = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (k > ((*r)->key))
    {
        addNode(&((*r)->right), k);
    }
    else if (k < ((*r)->key))
    {
        addNode(&((*r)->left), k);
    }
}

void searchNode(node **r, int k)
{
    if (*r == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\n NOT FOUND \n";
        return;
    }

    if ((*r)->key == k)
    {
        cout << "\n FOUND \n";
        return;
    }
    else if (k > ((*r)->key))
    {
        searchNode(&((*r)->right), k);
    }
    else if (k < ((*r)->key))
    {
        searchNode(&((*r)->left), k);
    }
}

void del(node **r, int k)
{
    if (*r == NULL)
        return;
    if ((*r)->key == k)
    {
        if ((*r)->left == NULL && (*r)->right == NULL)
        {
            (*r) = NULL;
            (*r) = NULL;
            free(r);
            return;
        }
        if ((*r)->left == NULL)
        {
            node* q = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            q = (*r)->right;
            (*r)->key = q->key;
            (*r)->left = q->left;
            (*r)->right = q->right;
            free(q);
            return;
        }
        if ((*r)->right == NULL)
        {
            node* q = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            q = (*r)->left;
            (*r)->key = q->key;
            (*r)->left = q->left;
            (*r)->right = q->right;
            free(q);
            return;
        }

        node* q = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        q = (*r)->right;

        while (q->left != NULL)
            q = q->left;

        (*r)->key = q->key;

        if (((*r)->right) == q)
        {
            (*r)->right = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            del(&q, q->key);
        }
    }
    else if (k > ((*r)->key))
    {
        del(&((*r)->right), k);
    }
    else if (k < ((*r)->key))
    {
        del(&((*r)->left), k);
    }
}

void print(node* r)
{
    if (r == NULL)
        return;

    print(r->left);
    cout << r->key << " ";
    print(r->right);
}

int main()
{
    node* root = NULL;
    addNode(&root, 11);
    addNode(&root, 5);
    addNode(&root, 4);
    addNode(&root, 8);
    addNode(&root, 6);
    addNode(&root, 10);
    addNode(&root, 9);
    addNode(&root, 19);
    addNode(&root, 12);
    addNode(&root, 30);
    addNode(&root, 20);
    addNode(&root, 50);
    addNode(&root, 31);
    addNode(&root, 37);
    addNode(&root, 35);
    addNode(&root, 38);
    print(root);

    del(&root, 9);
    cout << "\n 9 should be missing" << endl;
    print(root);
    searchNode(&root, 9);

    del(&root, 30);
    cout << "\n 30 should be missing" << endl;
    print(root);
    searchNode(&root, 30);

    del(&root, 8);
    cout << "\n 8 should be missing" << endl;
    print(root);
    searchNode(&root, 8);

    del(&root, 10);
    cout << "\n 10 should be missing" << endl;
    print(root);
    searchNode(&root, 10);

    del(&root, 11);
    cout << "\n 11 should be missing" << endl;
    print(root);
    searchNode(&root, 11);

    return 0;
}
```

When I am deleting root node the output should be 
`4 5 6 12 19 20 31 35 37 38 50`

whereas it is `4 5 6 12 12 19 20 31 35 37 38 50`

Comment: I've copied your code into the question itself and formatted it. (Make sure to do that yourself next time.)

Comment: Replace all `malloc` calls with `new`, and `free` with `delete`.

Comment: `node* q = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); q = (*r)->right;` These two lines are equivalent to just `node* q = (*r)->right;` (except the first option also leaks some memory).

Comment: *I have been searching for videos or articles on youtube as well as geeks for geeks* -- This is **not** the way to learn C++.  Time to get actual books written by peer-reviewed authors.  All you really wound up doing is writing `C` code with `cout` statements.

Comment: BTW, the `typedef struct` is not needed in C++.  The `struct` is enough to make a type.

Comment: IMHO, you should only include the header files that you need in order to resolve issues.  Do you really know what is in `<bits/stdc++.h>`?  I believe you could write a tree without using standard headers.

Comment: Since you are writing in C++, you should initialize the `node` links in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for everyone guidance ! Really appreciate your guidance will keep all the lessons in mind. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too complicated. There are multiple problems:

- `addNode()` allocates a new node but does not use it when recursing.
- `searchNode()` has a redundant comparison, and should probably take a simple constant `node` pointer.
- `del` should `free` the node pointed to by `r` before setting it to `NULL`.
- `del` should not allocate new nodes, but just modify the current node in place.

Here is a simplified and corrected version:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node {
    struct node *left = NULL;
    int key;
    struct node *right = NULL;
} node;

void addNode(node **r, int k) {
    if (*r == NULL) {
        node *q = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        q->key = k;
        q->left = NULL;
        q->right = NULL;
        *r = q;
        return;
    }
    if (k > (*r)->key) {
        addNode(&(*r)->right, k);
    } else
    if (k < (*r)->key) {
        addNode(&(*r)->left, k);
    }
}

void searchNode(const node *p, int k) {
    if (p == NULL) {
        cout << k << " NOT FOUND\n";
        return;
    }
    if (p->key == k) {
        cout << k << " FOUND\n";
        return;
    }
    if (k > p->key) {
        searchNode(p->right, k);
    } else {
        searchNode(p->left, k);
    }
}

void del(node **r, int k) {
    node *p = *r;
    if (p == NULL)
        return;
    if (k > p->key) {
        del(&p->right, k);
    } else
    if (k < p->key) {
        del(&p->left, k);
    } else {
        if (p->left == NULL) {
            (*r) = p->right;
            free(p);
            return;
        }
        if (p->right == NULL) {
            (*r) = p->left;
            free(p);
            return;
        }
        node *q = p->right;
        while (q->left)
            q = q->left;
        p->key = q->key;
        del(&p->right, p->key);
    }
}

void printrec(const node *r) {
    if (r != NULL) {
        printrec(r->left);
        cout << r->key << " ";
        printrec(r->right);
    }
}

void print(const node *r) {
    printrec(r);
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    node *root = NULL;
    addNode(&root, 11);
    addNode(&root, 5);
    addNode(&root, 4);
    addNode(&root, 8);
    addNode(&root, 6);
    addNode(&root, 10);
    addNode(&root, 9);
    addNode(&root, 19);
    addNode(&root, 12);
    addNode(&root, 30);
    addNode(&root, 20);
    addNode(&root, 50);
    addNode(&root, 31);
    addNode(&root, 37);
    addNode(&root, 35);
    addNode(&root, 38);
    print(root);

    cout << "deleting 9" << endl;
    del(&root, 9);
    print(root);
    searchNode(root, 9);

    cout << "deleting 30" << endl;
    del(&root, 30);
    print(root);
    searchNode(root, 30);

    cout << "deleting 8" << endl;
    del(&root, 8);
    print(root);
    searchNode(root, 8);

    cout << "deleting 10" << endl;
    del(&root, 10);
    print(root);
    searchNode(root, 10);

    cout << "deleting 11" << endl;
    del(&root, 11);
    print(root);
    searchNode(root, 11);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 19 20 30 31 35 37 38 50
deleting 9
4 5 6 8 10 11 12 19 20 30 31 35 37 38 50
9 NOT FOUND
deleting 30
4 5 6 8 10 11 12 19 20 31 35 37 38 50
30 NOT FOUND
deleting 8
4 5 6 10 11 12 19 20 31 35 37 38 50
8 NOT FOUND
deleting 10
4 5 6 11 12 19 20 31 35 37 38 50
10 NOT FOUND
deleting 11
4 5 6 12 19 20 31 35 37 38 50
11 NOT FOUND
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I recently started with coding so I am trying hard to learn these things ! sorry for formatting also.

Comment: @sudiptdabral: You are welcome! You can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.